# Create polygons around centroids, maintaining information

Tags: polygon-creation, centroids

I have a csv file which contains points (latitude, longitude) around all the African continent (see the picture for clarification). Apart from the latitude and longitude, it contains more information.

I would like to create rectangles of 0.5x0.5 degrees, with the centroid in each of the points of my csv. In the final output, I would like to have a shapefile of 0.5x0.5 degrees with the centroid in each of the points and with the rest of the information. Is it possible to do it?

I am using QGIS version 3.20.1

[image]

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to create a 0,5x0,5 grid covering your area of interest then use a spatial joint to get the point information to your grid cell.

Comment: Are your points equally spaced apart or are they "chaotic"?

Comment: @Zman3 Yes, the points are equally spaced. In fact, they form a grid cell of 0.5x0.5, but I need to create the area to join some stuff.

Comment: @J.R It could be an option. It's a good idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "[Rectangles, ovals, diamonds](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#rectangles-ovals-diamonds)" tool. Make sure the unit is degrees. If you use this tool, each grid polygon will have all information of the related point, but possible.

[image]

Result:

[image]

In case of getting gap or overlap, "[Snap geometries to layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#snap-geometries-to-layer)" tool can be used to fix that issue after "Rectangle, ovals, diamonds" tool. I personally haven't encountered such an error unless the "Rotation" value is specified.

Comment: Is this assuming the Points are equally spaced apart from each?

Comment: Thank you Kadir. Can you tell me where can I find that tool? I have my QGIS in Spain and it's a bit more difficult. I have never heared about that tool. Thank you.

Comment: @Zman3 Yes, the points are equally spaced

Comment: Navigate to "Processing toolbox (Ctrl+Alt+T) > Vector geometry > Rectangles, ovals, diamons"

Comment: If topology is important note that this solution could give some error like gap or overlap

Comment: @J.R "Snap geometries to layer" tool can be used to fix that issue after "Rectangle, ..." tool.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz It really works. Thank you so much. What kind of errors can I find it? It seems to me very fine. I would like to create an area around the centroid to join some stuffs.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz you should add that to your answer