# Counting number of distinct areas in cell using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, count, africa

On the figure below, I have:

- a shapefile of cells of 0.5x0.5 degrees around the African continent
- a shapefile of different regions in Africa

[image]

I would like to count the number of separate regions which pass through out each cell (see the second picture for an example). In the selected cell, there are three separations (three regions).

Hence, in the final output, I would like to assign a three to that cell. I would like to do it with every cell of my grid.

My version of QGIS is 3.20.1.

[image]

**Second problem:** when I try to do the suggestion of @BERA

I do what @BERA suggested (look the screenshot). "polygons" is my grid cell and border_tribes is the shapefile with the regions. However, I do not obtain the results. In fact, in every cell I obtain a value of 1 for each grid cell. In the second image, I attach another screen shot of the kind of results I obtain. The number should be 3 but it appears 1.

[image]

[image]

**Third problem:** when I try to do @BERA suggested in the comments as a possible solution to problem 2

When I change "borders_tribes" by grid, I obtain a result of 8 in each cell. I attach a picture of what I am doing and an example of the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show the attribute table of poligoni layer

Comment: You havent got an attribute called `borders_tribes` in your `Poligoni` layer. If gid, ccode or country is unique you can use any of them. That is why your calculation doesnt work

Comment: Thank you @BERA for your answer. So, instead of border_tribes, which is the shapefile with the regions I would like to account for each cell, should I change it by gid, which is unique for each cell?

Comment: I have edited my answer because when I did when you told me I am still not having what I would like to have

Comment: Would it be possible if you share this data with us?

Comment: Do you mean the two shapefiles? I create a grid cell in the way suggested here.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423507/create-polygons-around-centroids-maintaining-information . And the other shape file is https://scholar.harvard.edu/nunn/pages/data-0, where says "ethnic murdock maps" @Taras, do you know why it does not work what BERA suggested?

Comment: Yes, i mean both shapefiles. Can you please share them separately, there are two many files on the https://scholar.harvard.edu/nunn/pages/data-0. Perhaps it is matter of Projection.

Comment: Yes, tell me how I can do it.

Comment: Is it possible that the formula is not well? I am not sure what I should write in "regions" and kom_kod. In 'regions' should I put my grid file or my regions file? and in Kom_kod should I write the gid?

Comment: WeTransfer or dropbox or Google Drive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative using Processing tools:

Search for "[Join Attributes By Location (Summary)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?#join-attributes-by-location-summary)" in the [processing toolbox](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/de/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html). Choose the following settings:

- <kbd>Base Layer</kbd>: Your `Grid Layer`
- <kbd>Join Layer</kbd>: Your `Regions Layer`
- <kbd>Geometric Predicate</kbd>: `Intersects`
- <kbd>Fields to summarise</kbd>: A `unique key` of your Regions layer
- <kbd>Summaries to calculate</kbd>: `Count` and/or `Unique`

Run it. Output is a copy of your grid layer containing the count and/or unique count of intersections with your regions layer.

[image]

Example result:

[image]

In case you cannot find the processing toolbox, go to <kbd>View</kbd> -> <kbd>Panels</kbd> and enable <kbd>Processing Toolbox</kbd>. Then type the name of the processing tool into the search box:

[image]

Comment: It really works!! Thank you so, so much!!!

Answer (score 7):

Use Field Calculator:

```
array_length(array_distinct(overlay_intersects( 'regions', kom_kod)))
```

Replace regions with the name of your region layer, and kom_kod with some unique region attribute

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to do it but I am not understanding very well how to do it.  When I go to "Field Calculator" it appears a difference screen than the one in your comment. I have to fill the "input layer", which I guess I should put there my grid. But after I am not sure what I should do. When you say "region layer" do you refer to the grid cell?

Comment: When I try to do it, it says to me "Parser error with formula expression "array_length(array_distinct(overlay_intersects( 'Polígono'), borders_tribes)))": 
array_distinct function is called with wrong number of arguments. Expected 1 but got 2.
Execution failed after 0.09 segundos"

Comment: remove closing parenthesis nest to `Poligono`. it has to be like `.....ects( 'Polígono', bord......`

Comment: Thank you @Lilium. With that formula does not appear the error but it's not doing well the calculation because it always appears a 1 in the output. Do you know why this can happen?

Comment: @OgeiD you can try replacing `kom_kod` with `$id`, maybe this solves your _1 result_ issue.

Comment: @MrXsquared Adding $id also works this procedure!! Thank you! Your solution in the answer below also works!. What exactly $id does? Thank you again!

Comment: @OgeiD `$id` returns the unique id of a feature. It is not related to an attribute. It ensures to be always available and always be unique.

Comment: @MrXsquared Perfect, thank you! It was really helpful!