# Counting number of distinct polygons in an area using Python

Tags: python

I have:

1. a shapefile of cells around the African continent (polygon shapefile)
2. a shapefile of different regions in Africa (polygon shapefile)

I would like to count the distinct number of regions which intersect with each cell. That is, I would like to have a variable ("count_reg" see code below) for each cell with the number of regions which intersect the cells.

The exact same question has been asked here and it has solved by QGIS [Counting number of distinct areas in cell using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423529/counting-number-of-distinct-areas-in-cell-using-qgis). However, I have not found a way to do it in Python, there are a lot of questions counting the number of points inside a polygon, but no one counting the distinct number of areas intersecting inside a polygon.

This is what I am trying:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

example_int = gpd.overlay(cells, regions, how='intersection')
example_int['count_reg'] = 1
example_int_count=example_int[['count_reg','ID']].groupby(['ID']).agg('count')
```

where cells is a shapefile file of cells around the African continent, regions is a shapefile of different regions in Africa, and variable "ID" is the unique identifier of each cell in the cells shapefile.

It does not give any error but it assigns the same number to variable "count_reg", so it's not working.

Comment: Which Python library are you using?

Comment: Please include a code attempt that includes your imports. From that we’ll be able to see what spatial library you are asking about.

Comment: Are both cells & regions multipolygon shapefiles?

Comment: They are both Polygon shapefiles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use a right join:

```
import geopandas as gpd

# We loads some polygons (us states) and some points (elevation data):
url_poly = r'https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.geojson'
url_points = r'https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_geography_regions_elevation_points.geojson'
dfpoly = gpd.read_file(url_poly) 
dfpoints = gpd.read_file(url_points)

# We use a right join followed by a groupby in order to count the number of points 
# inside each polygon:
dfpoly.sjoin(dfpoints,how='right').groupby(['name_left'])['name_left'].count()
```

And the result looks like this:

```
name_left
Alaska            2
California        3
Colorado          2
Idaho             1
Maine             1
Montana           1
...
```

Note that if your two geodataframes contain polygons, then a polygon can be intersected more than once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What should I include in 'name_left'? It gives me an error: "KeyError: 'name_left'". My regions shapefile are not points are different regions around Africa, should it work that code?

Comment: It is just an example, `name_left` should be the name of the unique identifier of yours cells. In your case it looks like `ID` your UID. So `cells.sjoin(regions,how='right').groupby(['ID'])['ID'].count()` should do the job. And yes it will work with all kind of geometries that support an intersect condition.

Comment: It works! Thank you!